# Presto SQL Exploding Array to rows (but randomly sampled 100 rows)

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a huge table with an array column. I know the code to explode array to rows, however, I only want to explode the array to get 100 rows and stop - trying to save on compute cost of the query.
Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        u.ids AS final_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY
                random()
        ) AS seqnum
    FROM raw
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(raw.ids) u(ids)
    WHERE
        u.ids IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        1
)
WHERE
    seqnum <= 100;
```

Comment: You can not do it much better, as you want random 100 ids from an array that first must be unneted first, to even get them, you would save much time don't having arrays, so to get better performance normalize your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the LIMIT 100 statement after the WHERE clause in the subquery, you can restrict the number of rows returned to 100. This will help save on compute costs by avoiding unnecessary processing of additional rows.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to get some ("first") 100 unique ids you can use `distinct` + `limit`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(arr) as (
    values array[1,2,3,4],
        array[11,12,13,14],
        array[21,22,23,24]
)

-- query
select distinct id
from dataset,
    unnest(arr) as t(id)
limit 5; -- use 100 here
```

Output:

```
 id  
---- 
  1  
  2  
  3  
  4  
 11
```